# Why did Sharon not pay for the movie ticket?

Tags: plot-explanation, once-upon-a-time-in-hollywood

In [Once Upon A Time In Hollywood (2019)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7131622/), we see Sharon Tate walking past a movie theater that is featuring a movie with her in it. She decided to watch it and asks to buy one ticket. The attendant told her it was $0.75 and as she went to pay, Sharon told the attendant that she was in the movie and eventually made her way into the movie theater for free.

Why? She was well-off if not rich, so why do this? I do not think it was just to get attention because she specifically said, "What if I was in the movie?" as opposed to just saying, "You know, I am in this movie!".

Comment: Frankly it sounds as though she was just seeing what she could get away with. Whether she could afford the ticket was secondary.

Comment: @Paulie_D It did not seem that way in the scene, but I'm having a hard time coming up with another explanation. What, if anything, did her making it known she was in the movie do to move the story line? It didn't change her character or have any impact on the story line as far as I could see. It also didn't make sense why she would even be in the theater, so I'm guessing maybe it has a meaning outside of the movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sharon is depicted as a cheerful, playful and generous character.
She for example makes friends with a hitchhiker met in the street, always sports a smile.

Getting inside the theater without having to pay, playing on the fact that she had a role in the movie, was a game that she enjoyed very much, as well as she enjoyed watching the movie, and enjoyed watching the public reactions.

What else can we expect from an actor / actress, more than see them play?

It was also enjoyable to be acknowledged as an actress, more than boringly paying an anonymous ticket.
The ticket booth attendants were also pleased to host a star, it was generous of Sharon to create that moment with them.

Director Tarantino commented about the movie that he did not want to focus on the tragedy perpetrated by Mason's gang, but honor Mrs Tate's memory by remembering how full of life she was.

The character of Sharon Tate in this movie is an incarnation of Life, Fun, Joy.
The purpose of this part of the movie is to convey this idea.

Comment: I don't disagree, I was thinking it was to get the audience to love her more even though we all knew her fate and I'm sure QT set it up so that we were expecting her to meet that fate, only to be rewarded with the ending we got. Purposely messing with the emotions of the audience.